# How can I get permission to save file for flet app on android?

Tags: python, android, file-permissions, flet

I'm building an app with python flet that generate some text content and allow user to choose target folder to save them (as a .txt file).

Here is the sample code for file saving I'm trying to use:

```
import os
import flet as ft

def main(page:ft.Page):
    
    # Function to Create Text File
    def on_dialog_result(e: ft.FilePickerResultEvent):
        trg = e.path
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(trg,"Test.txt"),"w+",encoding="utf8") as fl:
                fl.write("Boo!")
            fl.close()
            res = "Save to "+trg
        except Exception as e:
            res = str(e)
        pth.value = res
        page.update()
    
    # File Picker Object
    file_picker = ft.FilePicker(on_result=on_dialog_result)
    page.overlay.append(file_picker)

    # Message Display
    pth = ft.Text()
    
    # Add to Page
    page.add(
        ft.ElevatedButton(
            "Choose files...",
            on_click=lambda _: file_picker.get_directory_path()
        ),
        pth,
    )
    page.update()

ft.app(target=main)
```

But after I build apk (with flet build cli tool) and tested on the emulator, it throws the "Permission denied" error.

[Error Message on Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLzVR.png)

Is there any possible way to enable the file saving permission for my flet app?

What I've tried :

1. The file access permission has enabled in the android system settings.
2. File picker can view and get the folder path, but can not save anything to the path.

Comment: You picked the wrong folder. Who created that folder? On Android 11+ devices your app can only save files in all public directories on external storage that are already there. Please next time write full path in your post.